# Jackson: Generate a schema with mutually exclusive properties

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I would like to generate a JSON schema for my POJO, and enforcing the constraint that only one attribute could be set.

```
class MyClass
{
   int a;
   
   int b;
}
```

and I need to generate the following schema (or equivalent).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
   "oneOf": [
     {"required": ["a"],  "not":  {"required": ["b"]}},    
     {"required": ["b"],  "not":  {"required": ["a"]}}   

     ],
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  
}
```

Ideally through Jackson annotation, but open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The schema you have there should work. You can also simplify it by removing the `not` clauses, so just:

```json
  "oneOf": [
     {"required": ["a"] },    
     {"required": ["b"] }  
   ],
   ...
```